# How to get 5 previous and 5 next lines using streamreader?

Tags: c#, streamreader

i would like to get 5 lines above and 5 lines under a current line. I am using Streamreader to read line by line and Regex to find a line with my pattern (a current line is the line where regex found a pattern).
Any advise would be appreciated.
Edit: files weigh at ~15GB so i cannot store them in memory.

Comment: StreamReaders are not really well designed to go backwards, you might be better of keeping the last 5 lines in a queue and using that instead (infact you may want to take all 11 lines and work with all of them ouside of the StreamReader and instead work with them inside a `Queue<string>`).

Answer (score 1):

Why not store these 5 lines (before/after)?

```
var cache= new Queue<string>();

 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        cache.Enqueue(reader.ReadLine());
        if(cache.Count() > 11)
             cache.Dequeue(); // clear old stuff

        if(cache.Count() == 11) // now you have your 5 before and 5 after
            {
              var myRow = cache.ElementAt(6); // do stuff
            }
    }
```

Comment: This looks nice. Thanks!. And now is it possible to easily change 'myRow' to string variable and have it as a main line to look for regex pattern in it? myRow then would be always in the middle of 11 lines going through the whole text file.

Comment: myRow is already a string as you are storing just strings in a queue

Comment: Tested and implemented in my code. Many thanks for help!